# How get Firebase pushmessage FCM if application is down

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want add push cloud message in my application. I add in manifect:

```
<service
        android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and add MyFirebaseMessagingService class and interface for it. If my application is run, I get message as RemoteMessage in my service. If application is down, push message receiver android and show notification in top part of the screen. I click this push, my application runninig and mainAcrivity have intent extras. Code in mainActivity onCreate:

```
if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            Object value = getIntent().getExtras().get(key);
            Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
        }
    }
```

Logcat output:

```
Key: google.delivered_priority Value: high
Key: google.sent_time Value: 1574665753356
Key: google.ttl Value: 2419200
Key: google.original_priority Value: high
Key: from Value: 69200725691
Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1574665753390474%7139185571391855
Key: collapse_key Value: ru.ittest.freezio_senser
```

Why I receiver no RemoteMessage? How can I get RemoteMessage use this keys?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"notification":{"title":"YOUR TITLE","body":"YOUR BODY"},
 "to": "your device token",
 "data":{
 "project_type": "Remodel",
 "name": "Start 45 "
     }
 }
```

Your notification response look like this . if your notification response contain this notification tag`"notification":{"title":"YOUR TITLE","body":"YOUR BODY"},`
then if app running then onMessageReceived method will call or if app is killed then onMessageReceived method won't call . To solve this problem you have to `"notification":{"title":"YOUR TITLE","body":"YOUR BODY"},` from notification response.

And you want to open specific activity on onclick of notification.
Add this codes in activity tag in manifest 
`<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NotificationActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>`

And replace intent in Notification code in onMessageReceived 
`val intent = Intent("NotificationActivity")`

Pass that this intent in pendingIntent
`val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,101,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)`

Comment: I ask no it. In documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive I can see: "Notification: system tray
Data: in extras of the intent." But really in extras is:
Key: google.delivered_priority Value: high
Key: google.sent_time Value: 1574665753356
Key: google.ttl Value: 2419200
Key: google.original_priority Value: high
Key: from Value: 69200725691
Key: google.message_id Value: 0:1574665753390474%7139185571391855
Key: collapse_key Value: ru.ittest.freezio_senser
Where is message title, body, image URI? How can I see it use extras?

Comment: I look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/42279260#42279260. In this post and in google documentation getIntent().getExtras() ->  get body key, "//bundle must contain all info sent in "data" field of the notification" . But in really - no contain.

Comment: that's true. You have dynamically store that data in onMessageReceived method.

Answer (score 0):

I find decide for it problem.

1. Thanks for Arthur Thompson: "the title body and image is not available when the user taps on the notification. If you want to get that data you will have to add it to the "data" payload of the message you are sending."
2. Add payload in firebase console:
   [image]
3. Now info received in MainActivity as:

   Bundle bungle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if ( bungle != null) {
           Object title = bungle.get("title");
           ....
    }